# Problem loading a PyTorch model into an application from a virtual machine

Tags: python, memory, pytorch, segmentation-fault

I am experiencing a problem loading a PyTorch model into an application I am developing from a virtual machine. I have created an instance of the model using the same file path that works correctly in a standalone script, but when I try to load it from my application, I get a segmentation error.

Indeed, here I am loading a pytorch model in a `test.py` file on a virtual machine:

```
model = UC_Model(pModel_filepath="/mnt/confiance/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_La_Organisacion_Anomaly_Detection/models/trained_perceiver/best_model_spectra")
print("model: ", model)
```

The model loads normally:

```
model:  <UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection.UC_Model object at 0x7f687d869a00>
```

But when I do it from the application I am developing, I get the following problem:

```
   .create Model from '/mnt/confiance/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_La_Organisacion_Anomaly_Detection/models/trained_perceiver/best_model_spectra'
./kaa.sh: line 48: 1870463 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python3 kaa.py $1
```

So I'm in the same virtual machine.

Here is the code of the application I created to load the model from the :

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Launch the inference computation
# @param pDictParams : parameter dictionary
# @return parameter dictionary updated
def launchInference(pDictParams):
    TUI.TUIprint("Action: Inference","Action")

    # create the model instance
    if has_method(pDictParams['pluginUCXAI'],'UCXAI_createModel'):
        print("pDictParams['pluginUCXAI']: ", pDictParams['pluginUCXAI'])
        aiModel=pDictParams['pluginUCXAI'].UCXAI_createModel(pDictParams)
```

En `pDictParams['pluginUCXAI']` tenemos una instanciacion de una classe, `UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection_Xplique`:

```
import UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Class for Use case vs Library
class UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection_Xplique(kaasrc.plugin_collection.Plugin):
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Class constructor
    # @param self : l'instance de la classe
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.nom = "UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection"
        self.description = "Detect bad vibrations in time series"
        self.modeles = ["PerceiverLogit"]
        self.bibliotheque = "Xplique"
        self.methodes = ["Hsic","Occlusion","KernelShap","Rise","Lime","Sobol"]
        self.metriques = None
        self.UC=UCLaOrganisacionAnomalyDetection

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Create an instance of the model
    # @param pDictParams : parameter dictionary
    # @return the instance of the model
    # @remark Call directly UC_createModel() of UC model
    def UCXAI_createModel(self,pDictParams):
        return self.UC.UC_createModel(pDictParams)
```

and UC.UC_createModel(pDictParams) is:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Create an instance of the model
# @param pDictParams : parameter dictionary
# @return the instance of the model
def UC_createModel(pDictParams):
    # shortcuts
    pModelBase=pDictParams['modelBase']
    pModelpath=pDictParams['modelpath']
    pModelfile=pDictParams['modelfile']
    pCode=pDictParams['code']

    # get model file
    ficModel=os.path.join(pModelBase,pModelpath,pModelfile)
    print("   .create Model from '%s'"%ficModel,flush=True)

    # create model instance from 'model' parameter
    aiModel=UC_Model(ficModel)
    print("      ",aiModel.name,"-/-",pCode,flush=True)
```

And I think the core dump arrives with `aiModel=UC_Model(ficModel)`.

I think it must be a graphics card problem. I always take CUDA=0 in the application

Comment: My simplest solution is reinstalling with pip instead of conda. (check cuda version)